# Non Boolean comparisons in flow.switch().case() Django-Viewflow

Tags: python, django, workflow, django-viewflow

I have a standar viewflow flow process, in one of the states id want to split my proccess based on the text value that is introduced in one of the fields. I have defined my field of interest this way in models.py

estado_de_aprobacion= models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=REVIEW_CHOICES)

my choices:

```
REVIEW_CHOICES = (
   ('APROBACION_FINAL', 'Aprobar definitivamente'),
   ('APROBACION_NUEVO_REVISOR', 'Enviar a otro revisor'),
   ('DEVOLVER_EJECUTOR','Devolver al ejecutor')
)
```

so basically what happens is that a drop list is displayed so the user can choose one of the options, and based on that I appliy the followinf split in the flow:

```
split =(
        #If(lambda activation: activation.process.aprobacion_final)
        flow.Switch()
        .Case(this.end, cond=((lambda act: act.process.estado_de_aprobacion)=='APROBACION_FINAL'))
        .Case(this.revisor_check, cond=((lambda act: act.process.estado_de_aprobacion)=='APROBACION_NUEVO_REVISOR'))
        .Case(this.ejecutar, cond=((lambda act: act.process.estado_de_aprobacion)=='DEVOLVER_EJECUTOR'))
    )
```

I assume that the lamba expression returns the value contained in the specified proccess atributes but since the comparisson isn't working im thinking its wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's unpack what is going on in the `cond` value.

```
cond=((lambda act: act.process.estado_de_aprobacion)=='APROBACION_FINAL')
```

`(lambda act: act.process.estado_de_aprobacion)` returns a function which extracts the relevant field from `act`.
Then you are comparing this to `=='APROBACION_FINAL'`, which is always going to fail because you are comparing a lambda function and a string.
So the actual value of `cond` being passed to the function is `False`.

I assume `cond` need to be a function that returns true or false? In which case you should do the comparison in the lambda function.

```
cond=lambda act: act.process.estado_de_aprobacion=='APROBACION_FINAL'
```

The extract parentheses in the original code are unnecessary, and are in fact probably the source of the problem.